# Swithcpage or new tab is not working in karate framework - it is always pointing to first page

Tags: karate

Im facing the issue with switching the tab/page.

1. when I login to my admin site, I enter credentials and gave hotel id and click on the link to navigate to particular hotel site, which is different site opens in new tab(with the SSO login). it is opening a new tab but Im not able to locate any elements in that page and driver is not pointing to new page.
   tried - Swithpage(0), Switchpage(new url/Title), karate version 0.9.6- nothing working
   when I use match of Driver.title- it is giving the tile of first page , so Im not able to do anything in my new page.
   Im stuck here. could you please help me here.

Comment: also try latest versions ( 1.2.0.RC4 ) or follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks Peter for the quick response. New version worked  :)